# Unable to send email with BlackBerry simulator

Tags: blackberry-simulator

I'm using the Blackberry simulator,trying to send a message still cannot send email messages from the simulator...so how to send email in BlackBerry Simulator...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/1075/BlackBerry%20Email%20and%20MDS%20Services%20Simulator%20Package%20Release%20Notes.pdf